# Share login between nuxt + laravel + passport + wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I have a website which is a service shop built on nuxt + laravel. I've been using passport's personal access token for login there.
Now I'll be having a wordpress site for a product shop.
I want to share the login state of the nuxt site to the wordpress site, through a login button (Login with XYZ) like we have on facebook/google/github etc Oauth2 login.

I tried using [miniOrange plugin](https://plugins.miniorange.com/laravel-passport-as-an-oauth-server) . But it turns out its able only to share login of the default laravel site (session based web route login). But what I need is share the tokenized authentication.

N.B : There's no password required for login, it is OTP login

Comment: You might want to set up an oauth server that handles all the logins.

Comment: @CésarEscudero, yes I know. I already mentioned that I'm using passport for setting up oauth server, but how can I share it with wordpress ? miniOrange plugin is not helping unless I use web route login, but I'm bound to use api route,See?